# Is it possible to define RGB colors to be used in MaTeX? How?

Tags: graphics, color, fonts, matex

My system: Windows 10, Mathematica 11.2, MikTeX 2.9

I am in the process of learning more about the features of Szabolcs Horvát's nice paclet. This time I am toying with the color choices for the produced text. I have this (questionably) bright idea to match the colors of components of a figure with the accompanying MaTeX-outputs. Unfortunately the sets of available colors don't quite match.

After the start

```
In[1]:=<< MaTeX`
In[2]:=SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}"}]
```

many things work splendidly. But the input

```
In[3]:=Graphics[Text[MaTeX["\\color{orange}{\\bf{x}^\\perp}", FontSize -> 16], {2, 1.3}]];
```

gives the error message saying that the color `orange` is not defined. Hardly a surprise given that a bit of digging reveals that orange is not available in the prescribed LaTeX-package.

If I were writing either LaTeX or Mathematica code I would know what to do. In Mathematica I would use `RGBColor` with appropriate parameters. In LaTeX I would try something like `\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}` to define a color in a macro.

How can I do this with MaTeX?

- load a different TeX-package, which?
- define the desired color by inserting a macro, how?

Answer (score 2):

I was at my dullest. Or, if not that, mostly oblivious to what the `In[2]` command in the snippet from the question body does.

Apparently it is possible to pass several LaTeX-commands within the preamble. A bit of testing shows that

```
   In[2]:=SetOptions[MaTeX, 
     "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}", 
       "\\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.6,0}"}]
```

does exactly what you might wistfully hope it would :-)

Comment: Also *magenta* may be more distinguishable from *red* than *orange*, and hence a better choice.

Comment: Mathematica also uses the range $[0, 1]$ in `RGBColor`, as well as _most_ other constructs.